# Sizing mesh without deform it with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

Hi. I’m trying to make a sheet metal with geometry nodes. I use two attributes(width and length) for sizing the mesh in the input field. The width is OK when the value is modified but the mesh is deformed when the length is changed. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this helps?

[image]

By using uvmap, your x/y keeps stable so your calculation keeps stable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Chris. I found the solution.